# Stop button from moving when resizing page

Tags: html, css

I have this one whole image that I have placed statically on my site however I want the parts to be clickable via a transparent button. I've got the button created however I want it to stay in its position if I had a different sized window etc.

Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<img id="container" src="recentProjectsV2.jpg" />

<a href="http://gcseanswers.co.uk/" button id="invisibleButton1"> GCSE Answers </a>
```

CSS:

```
invisibleButton1 {

    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 45px;
    top: -170px;

    background-color: transparent;
    border: 10px, orange;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle please, also: what have you tried, what happens, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Post ALL of your html code and css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the position of your button from relative to absolute if you want it to stay in the EXACT same position when resized. If you want it to stay in the exact same position, like dead center vertically and horizontally, regardless of window size, I would suggest using flexbox though that will only work with IE 10 and up.

```
.invisibleButton1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 45px;
    top: -170px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 10px, orange;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex however same problem when I start using different axis it moves. Any thoughts or will I have to use flexbot?

Comment: Or would I have to include it all including the image to keep it in one area?

Comment: Are you able to create a jsFiddle? I am curious to see the container that this button is in.

Answer (score 0):

The button does stay in the position you told it to stay in.

Code:

CSS:

```
<style>
.invisibleButton1 {

position: relative;
width: 290px;
height: 100px;
left: 45px;
top: -170px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 10px, orange;
font-size: 0;
cursor: pointer;

}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
<img id="container" src="logo.jpg" />
<a href="http://gcseanswers.co.uk/"> <button id="invisibleButton1"> GCSE   Answers </button> </a>
</body>
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, please clarify your question and add your code.

Comment: Sorry about my bad wording - I have this button however I need it just to stay in one position and need to specify its axis as there's going to be multiple of these buttons in the same area. However, when I resize the page it of course keeps its axis numbers so I need a way of making it stay in the same place even the window is at a different size. If that makes any sense...!